# Switch по Generic type

Tags: javascript, ооп, typescript

Мой код:

```
interface A {
  name: string;
}

interface B {
  name: string;
}

function foo<T>(): string {
  if (T === A) return 'A';
  else return 'B';
}

const result = foo<A>();
console.log(result); // 'A'
```

Как, в зависимости от интерфейса, передаваемого в метод/функцию, делать то или иное действие?

Comment: Поскольку в TS типы структурные, а не номинальные, то эти два интерфейса абсолютно идентичны.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, но даже если бы они были совершенно разными, его функции без параметров это бы не помогло...

Comment: @Qwertiy это да. Но в любом случае стоит понимать разницу

Answer (score 2):

Невозможно. Информация о типах есть только во время компиляции.

Если тип `T` является классом, то можно явно передавать его конструктор в функцию.

Если передаётся объект данного типа, то можно написать функцию, которая отличает один тип от другого и в `if` вызвать её.